# JSON > Model > Strongly Typed View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Im new to the ASP and MVC world - and I havent worked with JSON before.

I am calling an API which returns JSON data, which I then convert to a typed list, List. Debugging shows me that the deserialization from JSON to List worked.

I then try to return this to my view

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StoryBacklog()
    {

        List<Story> StoryList = new List<Story>();
        StoryList.Add(new Story { name = "first" });
        StoryList.Add(new Story { name = "second" });
        StoryList.Add(new Story { name = "third" });
        StoryList.Add(new Story { name = "fourth" });
        StoryList.Add(new Story { name = "fifth" });

        StoryList.AddRange(GetStoryList()); /**/
        return View(StoryList);
    }
```

But when I do this, the resulting page renders the JSON data then HTML. If I comment out the line marked with /**/, I get the expected result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does "_But when I do this, the resulting page renders the JSON data **then** HTML_" mean?

Comment: I don't see any JSON and what does GetStoryList do?

Comment: post your view code please

Comment: are you sure your routes are correct and you are hitting the right actionresult?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Please place detail code to investigate problem

Comment: We need to see the code for `GetStoryList` to be any help.